# Sort files based on similarity of file names

Tags: shell, find, filenames, move

I have a directory structure which contains many files. I want to find similar files recursively and sort them based on their names.

The easy part: find all files named `f*.ext` and move them to a certain directory, let's say `dir1`.

But now I want to go through the tree again and find all `t*.ext` which have a match in `dir1`. For example, for `dir1/f12345.jpg` find the corresponding `source-tree/t12345.jpg` (if it exists) and move it to `dir2`.

In the end, every for every `dir2/t*.ext` there should be a `dir1/f*.ext`. All `source-tree/t*.ext` who don't have a `dir1/f*.ext` should remain where they are.

Comment: What is the criteria for a "similar" match? Is it always that only the first character of the filename and the filename suffix after the dot is different?  You also mention `t*.ext` in `dir2`, but as far as I can see, `dir2` contains `t*.ext` files at that point, not `t*.jpg` files.

Comment: in my case the basename from the second character on and the extension have to be the same. t12345.jpg and f12345.jpg or t23456.bmp and f23456.bmp or t34567.txt and f34567.txt.

Comment: You can combine files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
# Create dir2:
mkdir dir2
# After moving f* to dir1, loop through these files (dir1/f*):
for f in dir1/f*; do
    # get the basename, cut off the "f" and put a "t" instead:
    t=source-tree/t$(basename "$f" | cut -c 2-)
    # If that file exists, move it to dir2
    [ -f "$t" ] && mv "$t" dir2
done
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: `[ -f filename ]` checks if a file with that filename exists, returning true or false, only if true, the part after `&&`  is executed. So, I assume you're inside the `source-tree` folder. I changed the script a bit ...

Comment: Found my typo before I saw your edit. :-) It works fine, thanks! And with your current edits you already helped me with my next question, getting deeper in the directory tree.

Comment: Ok, it works fine. My problem is, that the t*.ext are in multiple sudirectories like source-tree/here/t12345.jpg or source-tree/there/23456.jpg. I'm trying to figure out how use the full path of the file in the second part of the second line.

Comment: got it:  [ -f ./*/"$t" ] &&  t=`find ./*/ -name $t` && mv "$t" dir2